# Which is bigger: O(n*logn) or O(1)?

Tags: big-o

We are going over the master theorem in my algorithms class, and for one problem, I'm trying to compare nlogn vs 1 to figure out which case of the MT it falls under.  But I'm having a hard timing figuring out which is bigger.

Edit: This is for solving a recurrence problem.  The equation is T(n) = 2T(n/4) + N*LogN.  Just threw this in incase it helps.

Comment: o(1) means constant execution time. nlog(n) is variable execution time. should be obvious which one's "bigger", and at which times

Comment: Hint: does O(1) grows when n is increased?  does O(nlogn) grow as n increases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it this way:

- `O(N*LogN)` will increase with `N` in such a way that for any `X`, no matter how large, you can find a value of `N` such that `N*LogN` is greater than `X`.
- `O(1)` will stay the same, no matter what `N` is.

This means that `O(1)` is *asymptotically* better, i.e. for some (perhaps very high) value of `N` the `O(N*LogN)` will become slower.

Comment: So from this im getting that O(1) is better, but O(N*LogN) is bigger because it will increase with N?

Comment: @MikeGordon The *but* in your sentence doesn't really make sense. Bigger is worse here.

Comment: @MikeGordon When you compare algorithms using the "big O" notation, bigger always means "worse" (slower, takes more memory, uses more resources, and so on). `O(1)` is as good as any algorithm can possibly get - it is an equivalent of "just knowing the answer".

Comment: So would it be safe to say N*LogN = O(1) ?

Comment: @MikeGordon No, not at all! These are very different classes of algorithms.

Comment: This argument does not work. 2 - 1/n also increases with n, but is not asymptotically larger than 1.

Comment: @FalkHüffner I edited the answer to add more precision to the first statement.

Answer (score 0):

If an algorithm is O(NlogN) that means that there exists a number A and a quantity of execution time B, such that for any input size N greater than A, the execution time will be less than B times NlogN.

If an algorithm is O(1), that would mean that there exists some fixed amount of time C in which the algorithm would be guaranteed to complete regardless of the input size.

In comparing two algorithms, one of which is O(NlgN) and one of which is O(1), one will generally discover that the O(1) algorithm is faster for values of N that are sufficiently large, but in many cases the O(NlgN) algorithm may be faster for small values of N.

Indeed, while something like an O(N^3) or O(N^4) algorithm would generally seem pretty bad, it's possible that even an O(N^4) algorithm may outperform an O(1) algorithm if N is usually a small number (e.g. 1-5 or so) and never gets very big (even an occasional value of 50 could seriously dog performance).